# Who was feeding the prisoners of the Pit in the Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

It's been a while since I saw *The Dark Knight Rises* but something occurred to me. Who was feeding the prisoners when Bruce was imprisoned? I assume the Warlord fed them when he was in charge but who fed them once Bane took over?

Comment: I always assumed Bane's people were.  He made a point of wanting Bruce alive.  But then, *The Dark Knight Rises* doesn't exactly make what ya'd call "sense."

Comment: @nerrolken That just raises the question of why they didn't stop Bruce and the other prisoners from escaping.

Comment: Well that one's easy: the people in the pit are clearly being neglected.  Someone must drop off food every few days, and otherwise the pit is unguarded.  That's the whole purpose of the pit: they can't get out, so you don't need to worry about guards.

Comment: @nerrolken You mean the prison that Bane saw someone escape from?

Comment: Remember that thing I said about *TDKR* not making sense?

Comment: @nerrolken True. That would explain why Bane gave Bruce access to a doctor for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not apparent from the script, nor the novelisation quite who is feeding the inhabitants of The Pit. There's a brief mention of the Doctor being "paid" to keep Bruce alive and there seems to be bread and other foodstuffs in the prison, strongly suggesting that *someone* (Bane's henchmen? The League of Shadows? Local villagers?) are dropping food off every now and then, in quantities sufficient to feed the inhabitants.

> Bruce grimaced. He lay miserably atop the cot, from which he hadn’t
>   stirred for who knew how long. Feverish and weak, he’d lost all track
>   of time, drifting in and out of awareness. His head pounded, and the
>   searing pain in his back was a constant companion, even in his sleep.
>   Existence had become an endless ordeal he could never escape. He could
>   not even clean himself.
>
> “Do it for the pleasure,” he said bitterly. But the nameless European
>   placed a stale piece of bread to Bruce’s lip. He shrugged
>   apologetically.
>
> “They pay me more than that to keep you alive.”
>
> - <sub><sup>The Dark Knight Trilogy: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

---

> **PRISONER:** He asks if you would pay us to let you die. I told him you have nothing.
>
> **WAYNE:** Do it for the pleasure.
>
> [The Prisoner puts bread to Wayne’s lips.]
>
> **PRISONER:** They pay me more than that to keep you alive.
>
> [A chant gets Wayne’s attention. He rolls his head painfully to watch a
>   Tattooed Prisoner hand a thick rope to a Strong Man, who ties it
>   around his chest, watched by other Prisoners.]
>
> - <sub><sup>The Dark Knight Trilogy: The Complete Screenplays</sup></sub>